# styling marker icon and info window

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-markers

This is an image with some points having info window. when the cursor move to that point it shows info window.

[image]

```
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myMap() {
        var locations = [
  ['some info', 30.118802, 31.410364],
  ['some info', 33.616455, 73.096199],
  ['some info', 33.598394, 73.044135],
  ['some info', 21.673434, 39.160065],
  ['some info', 34.011382, 71.523476], ];
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.571394, 74.310374),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

This is the simple marker with simple info window code. but I need more marker icon and style for info.window and also the text without info.window like in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take one step at a time .. starting from the marker icon

you can assign a new icon to a marker this way :

```
var image = 'your_path/your_file.png';
// you can use the path below for test
// var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
   map: map,
   icon: image
 });
```

or if you have a marker already you can use

```
   marker.setIcon( image);
```